# DI with ILogger in Azure webJob

Tags: c#, azure, azure-application-insights, azure-webjobs, loggerfactory

I have an azure webjob project created in .net framework 4.6. i am trying to implement dependency injection with ILogger and log the information in application insights.

```
class Program
{
    private static IConfigurationRoot configuration;

    // Please set the following connection strings in app.config for this WebJob to run:
    // AzureWebJobsDashboard and AzureWebJobsStorage
    public static void Main()
    {
        var config = new JobHostConfiguration();

        if (config.IsDevelopment)
        {
            config.UseDevelopmentSettings();
        }
        var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                      .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
                      .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true)
                      .AddEnvironmentVariables();

        IServiceCollection serviceCollection = new ServiceCollection();
        ConfigureServices(serviceCollection);
        //config.JobActivator = new CustomJobActivator(serviceCollection.BuildServiceProvider());
        config.LoggerFactory = new LoggerFactory()
           .AddApplicationInsights(configuration.GetSection("ApplicationInsights")["InstrumentationKey"], null);
        config.UseTimers();
        var host = new JobHost(config);
        // The following code ensures that the WebJob will be running continuously
        host.RunAndBlock();
    }

    private static void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection serviceCollection)
    {
        serviceCollection.AddTransient<Functions, Functions>();
        serviceCollection.AddLogging();
    }
}
```

appSettings.json

```
{   
    "ApplicationInsights": {
        "InstrumentationKey": "8028437c-888-666-444-2cf3777106a8"
    }
}
```

Functions.cs

```
public class Functions
{
    private readonly ILogger<Functions> _logger;

    public Functions(ILogger<Functions> logger)
    {
        _logger = logger;
    }

    public void ProcessTimerMessage([TimerTrigger("0 */5 * * * *")]TimerInfo timerInfo, TextWriter log)
    {
        //LOG THIS IN APP INSIGHTS
        _logger.LogError("Error");
    }
}
```

I have also tried adding the below code in ConfigureServices method. But still no luck.

```
var telemetryClient = new TelemetryClient(new TelemetryConfiguration()
{
       InstrumentationKey = "<< Instrumentation Key >>"
});
serviceCollection.AddSingleton(x => telemetryClient).AddLogging();
```

Only the trace logs gets logged in app insights whereas the logger object logs doesnot appear. 
Please help

Comment: Hi, the webjob project is created from the webjob template or an console application?

Comment: Web Job template .NET Framework 4.6.1. I'm using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs SDK 2.2.0

Comment: I write a sample below, not a TimerTrigger, but the solution should be the same. If any another issue, please let me know.

Comment: i have tried this. But in this case even Log.Error goes as trace in app insights. I want it to go as exception. If i have another method in Functions.cs, then i want to log info or exceptions. Hence looking for dependency injection with which i can achieve this.

Comment: I tried use this line of code:  Log.LogError(new Exception(), "your error message"), and it can goes as exception. I also updated my answer, you can take a try and let me if it's ok.

Comment: Hi @Sanketh, have you solved your issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I created a webjob project from vs web job template, .net framework 4.6.1, steps as below:

step 1: create project
[image]

step 2: install the following package:

```
Install-Package Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs -version 2.2.0
Install-Package Microsoft.Extensions.Logging -version 2.0.1
Install-Package Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console -version 2.0.1
Install-Package Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Logging.ApplicationInsights -version 2.2.0
Install-Package System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager -version 4.4.1
```

step 3: in app.config, add following:
[image]

step 4: my program.cs:

```
  using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs;
  using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
  using System.Configuration;

    namespace WebJob7
    {

        class Program
        {

            static void Main()
            {
                var config = new JobHostConfiguration();
                var instrumentationKey =
                   ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["APPINSIGHTS_INSTRUMENTATIONKEY"];

                config.DashboardConnectionString = "";

                config.LoggerFactory = new LoggerFactory()
                    .AddApplicationInsights(instrumentationKey, null)
                    .AddConsole();

                if (config.IsDevelopment)
                {
                    config.UseDevelopmentSettings();
                }

                var host = new JobHost(config);

                host.RunAndBlock();
            }
        }
    }
```

step 5: my code in Function.cs:

```
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

namespace WebJob7
{
    public class Functions
    {
        // This function will get triggered/executed when a new message is written 
        // on an Azure Queue called queue.
        public static void ProcessQueueMessage([QueueTrigger("queue")] string message, ILogger logger)
        {
        //you can directly use this line of code.
        //logger.LogError(new Exception(),"it is a test error...");

        //or use the following code
        try
        {
            int i = int.Parse("123er");
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            logger.LogError(ex,"it's a exception here 0927..........");
        }

        }
    }
}
```

After execution, the logs are shown in azure portal -> go as Exception:
[image]

Click it to see details:
[image]

Comment: This worked. But i found another solution which worked. Removed "config.LoggerFactory = new LoggerFactory()
                    .AddApplicationInsights(instrumentationKey, null)" and added "serviceCollection.AddSingleton(new LoggerFactory().AddApplicationInsights("InstrumentationKey", null)". Using the above code solved my problem.

Comment: @Sanketh, congrats, and thanks for your sharing. But if my answer also works, could you please help mark it as an answer?

Comment: Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Logging.ApplicationInsights ??? That does not exist!

Comment: @HelloWorld, you mean the package does not exist now?